# MEF with MVC 4, get exported ApiControllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to build pluggable architecture with MEF and MVC. I have MVC application which will be responsible for loading the modules (other mvc projects). The idea is to copy-paste the module in some folder and the module should pop up.

Anyway, I wanted to get the exported (in terms of MEF Export) API controllers from the module assembly.

```
[Export("TestModuleApi", typeof(IHttpController))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class TestModuleApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        return "HomeApi";
    }
}
```

I couldn't find much information how I can achieve that.

However, I was able to get the 'normal' mvc controllers with a custom implementation of `IControllerFactory`, where in the `CreateController` method I get the requested controller from the exported objects of the `CompositionContainer`. 
But the `IControllerFactory` is providing only `IController` objects, not `IHttpController` (`ApiController`).

I tried to implement custom `IHttpControllerActivator` without success. When I tried to browse URL from the module (like `api\TestModuleApi\Get`) I am getting 404 and I don't even get into the custom activator's `Create` method.

Any help will be appreciated.